# Getting USB device handle in C#

Tags: c#, usb, hardware, device, handle

I'm trying to create an addon for KSP that would allow the usage of the MFD functions of the X52 Pro joystick within the game.

I've ran into an issue though, where I have no idea how to the the device handle for the joystick.

Does anyone know how I would get the device handle?

Comment: I can't answer you question directly, but does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj649944(v=vs.85).aspx help at all?

Comment: Sadly no, what I need is a void*(IntPtr to the C++ guys) that points to the device

Comment: Are you opening a pipe to the device yourself? If so, then CreateFile() will return the handle to you. I assume you are not, and you want to hook the handle. This is not going to be easy. What you probably need to do is insert a filter driver that you attach to the top of the joystick driver - then you can issue requests to that, a known interface, and relay them to the joystick device.

Comment: Well, I'll look into opening the pipe myself, seeing as so far theres no way to access it through unity for my uses

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass WinProc on your Window C#  Winforms class , since message.LParam and message.RParam are HID handles with semantic type HWND analogous  to MFC.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApplicationJoyStick
{
    public class Program : RichTextBox
    {

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to retrieve raw input data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hRawInput">Handle to the raw input.</param>
    /// <param name="uiCommand">Command to issue when retrieving data.</param>
    /// <param name="pData">Raw input data.</param>
    /// <param name="pcbSize">Number of bytes in the array.</param>
    /// <param name="cbSizeHeader">Size of the header.</param>
    /// <returns>0 if successful if pData is null, otherwise number of bytes if pData is not null.</returns>

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == (int)WindowMessages.RawInput)  // WindowMessages.RawInput = 0x00FF (WM_INPUT)
        {
            RAWINPUT input = new RAWINPUT();
            int outSize = 0;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUT));

            outSize = Win32API.GetRawInputData(m.LParam, RawInputCommand.Input, out input, ref size, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));
            if (outSize != -1)
            {
                if (input.Header.Type == RawInputType.Joystick)
                {
                          // Output X and Y coordinates of Joystick movements                  
               }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

}